# Write the plugin when Selecting the lookup flied and according to filed selection Show/Hide Address filed in form.....?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We Have Contact Entities in contact Entitie one lookup filed company Name in that lookup having two values 1.Account and 2.Contact . When we are selecting contact show the address filed when we select account hide the address filed we needs to write the plugin to Execute that works. Kindly any one help me on the same.

Thanks!!

Rajesh Singh

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need to make change on a form, you can't use plug-ins. Plug-ins are made for bussinees logics, like Update another record when the first one is created, make complex logic, etc...

What you need it is a javascript that executes on the OnLoad of the form and OnChange event in that OptionSet.

The lines you are looking for are:

```
function ShowField()
{
    // The field is present on the form so we can access to its methods        
    var optionSet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("custom_attribute");
    if (optionSet == undefined)
    {
        return;
    }

    // The control is present on the form so we can access to its methods
    var controlAddress = Xrm.Page.getControl("custom_address");
    if (controlAddress == undefined)
    {
        return;
    }

    var valueOptionSet = optionSet.getValue(); // This is the value you set creating the OptionSet
    switch (valueOptionSet) 
    {
        case 0: // Your account value, show

            controlAddress.setVisible(true);

        case 1: // Your contact value, hide

            controlAddress.setVisible(false);

        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

You need to register a web resource and register the event, if you need more information about the code or why this stuff is here and why this not just tell me.

Comment: Hi Sxntk Thanks for the same But Our Requirement is different we can perform that task through plugin.If some data will be come in some other source than not perform from client side code.Need to write the server side code.

Comment: Hi, you can't not perform changes to the interface with a plug-in, you just can modify data, if this is your requirement you need to mix both, a plug-in that updates that field and a javascript that shows that field. If you can be more specific with you requirement I can help you better.